# Triggering Event When Div of Class ".x" is Clicked Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

JS:

```
$(".x").click(function()
    {
        alert("hello");
        return false;
    });


$("#otherdiv").html("<div class='x'>Drag and drop values on the right to create a pivot table.</div><br />");
```

CSS:

```
div.x
{
    background-color: white; 
    border: dotted 1px; 
    cursor: pointer;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    left: 10%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

When I click the div with the class 'x', nothing happpens.

Comment: Um so is the class `x` or `error`? Not that it's related to the problem of course.

Comment: x. I changed it to 'x' to keep it generic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't attach the event handler with `click`, because your `<div>` is added dynamically. The `click` method only works existing elements. You have to use `live`*<sup>[[API Ref](http://api.jquery.com/live)]</sup>* or `delegate`*<sup>[[API Ref](http://api.jquery.com/delegate)]</sup>* instead.

---

**UPDATE:** From jQuery's `live` documentation:

> **As of jQuery 1.7**, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()`<sup>*[[API Ref](http://api.jquery.com/on/)]*</sup>  to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use the jQuery .live() function, which also attaches the event to all elements created in the future.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 2):

use delegate on body or container for .x class divs like: http://jsfiddle.net/MEEHN/

```
$('body').delegate('.x','click',function(){
   alert(1);
});

$('<div class="x">asd</div>').appendTo('body');
```